# Mongodb using $text in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to search in text with aggregate and I have the following code.Here is my aggregate query, but doesn't work. I expect to search first for the text and if find posts with that words in it to find user and then to query by user.name and the topic.

```
const posts = await Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $text: {
            $search: postWords ? `${postWords}` : /.*/,
            $caseSensitive: false,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "user",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$user",
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            {
              topic: {
                $regex: postTopic ? postTopic : /.*/,
                $options: "i",
                $exists: true,
              },
            },
            {
              "user.name": {
                $regex: postName ? postName : /.*/,
                $options: "i",
                $exists: true,
              },
            },
            { text: { $regex: postWords ? postWords : /.*/, $options: "i" } },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $skip: req.params.page ? (req.params.page - 1) * 10 : 0,
      },
      {
        $limit: 11,
      },
      {
        $project: {
          "user.password": 0,
          "user.active": 0,
          "user.email": 0,
          "user.temporaryToken": 0,
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the object **"text"** from the **match** query and put the **$text operator** straight away within the match query as follows:

```
db.notifications.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $text: {
                $search: "faizul"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Before executing the above make sure that you had made the **index type** as **text** for the **field** that you want to text search for.

In my case I had marked **agent_id** field as ***text IndexType***.

[image]

**Query Result:**
From the query you could see that I had simply entered faizul in the text search and not the full email address. Which works fine.

[image]

Comment: postWords is array or string separated with white spaces, if I tried to do lets say "asd dsa" and there is a text with that exactly the same words works, but if i try to turn around "dsa asd" that doesn't work, also edit my aggregate, so you can see it

Answer (score -1):

$text is an expression-level operator, not a field-level operator. See the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) for correct usage.

There can only be one text index defined on a collection and this index is used by the $text operator, therefore it is redundant to specify the field name(s) with $text.

Comment: Any ideas how to search in a string by array of words or something? And if there is any matches to return it aswell.

Comment: Joining words into a string with spaces works I believe.

Comment: Atlas provides excerpts: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/highlighting/#highlight-ref. Non-Atlas deployments do not.

Comment: Can you give me an example how should I implement this, because I tried anything and still 0 progress, Thank you!

Comment: How to implement what?

Comment: I want to search in a string with array( or other type) , because I'm making advanced search and I want to search by topic, user.name(creatorName) and keywords that are in array( or string separated with white space)