# MongoDB aggregate returning only specific fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following code:

```
const profiles = await Profile.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "user",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$user",
      },
      {
        $match: {
          "user.name": {
            $regex: q.trim(),
            $options: "i",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $skip: req.params.page ? (req.params.page - 1) * 10 : 0,
      },
      {
        $limit: 11,
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$_id",
          skills:{skills}
          user: { name: "$name" },
          user: { avatar: "$avatar" },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

I want to return only specific fields like skills _id and user.name and user.avatar, but this doesn't work. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in $group. I want to receive only these fields

```
 [
   {
     _id: 5ef78d005d23020ca847aa76,
     skills: [ 'asd' ],
     user: {
       _id: 5ef78c7c5d23020ca847aa75,
       name: 'Simeon Lazarov',
       avatar: 'uploads\\1593286096227 - background.jpg',
     }
   }
 ]
```

Comment: please upade questation with sample data

Comment: I edit my question to show you what i want to get in return, but with my query I'm getting all the info about profile

Comment: Have you tried using $project? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: Yes, but I'm really new to aggregation and I think I'm just trying it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `$project` to get specific fields.

After grouping add the below:

```
{
 $project: {_id:1, skills:1, user:1}
}
```

Projection value of **0** means that the field needs to be excluded, Value **1** represents inclusion of the field.

Document reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: I just remove $group at all and worked! Thank you! may I ask you 1-2 question as well

Comment: Thank you again! You can check my question here and if need more info just comment there! [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616465/mongodb-using-text-in-aggregate-query)

Comment: Also how to check if the user have the same id with the query object to do not return it `{"user._id": {$ne: req.user.id},},` something like this, but this doesn't work