# return specific fields from grouped docs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm using `$group` to return the docs based on their `level`.it is returning a fields array with their docs which are working fine.

I'm trying to return certain fields of the single doc.

current result :

```
"master": [
{
"_id": "63099a4c00b3c49e75e642e6",
"level": "master",
"uid": "l7AafULWLtP5mpcWKihdo",
"createdAt": "2022-08-27T04:15:08.905Z",
"updatedAt": "2022-08-27T04:15:08.905Z",
"slug": "text-2",
"__v": 0
}
],
```

Expected result :

```
"master": [
{
"uid": "l7AafULWLtP5mpcWKihdo",
"slug": "text-2",
}
],
```

`$group`:

```
   {
      $group: {
        _id: "$level",
        fields: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        fields: {
          $push: {
            k: "$_id",
            v: "$fields"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: "$fields" }
    },
    {
      $sort: { createdAt: -1 },
    },
```

is this possible to achieve? I'm new to MongoDB any help is appreciated

Comment: use [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB aggregate returning only specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620651/mongodb-aggregate-returning-only-specific-fields)